# Finding extreme values of two-variable polynomial expression without any calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization

Suppose you have to find the maximum value of the product $xyz$, with the following conditions:

- $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and all positive
- $x+y+z=a\,, \quad a\gt0$

Intuitively, the solution should be $x=y=z=a/3$, but I was wondering if it was possible to solve this problem without resorting to multivariable calculus, e.g. by algebraic manipulation of the expression $xy(a-x-y)$, in a similar way as with the univariate quadratic case $x^2+bx+c$. I'm particularly interested in the general method and line of reasoning for solving this kind of problems; any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Lookup the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: @dxiv I'm sorry, I don't get it. Could you tell me where to look in particular?

Comment: The link takes you to $\,\sqrt[3]{xyz} \le \dfrac{x+y+z}{3}\,$ with equality iff $x=y=z$, which solves the case you posted.

Comment: Thank you, that's great. How does one see it at a glance?

Comment: Practice, there really is no substitute or shortcut. Once you've seen a few, you'll recognize them more quickly.